# 3D Domain for a triple integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, integral-domain

I have the following domain:
$$D = \{(x,y,z) \mid x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 4, x^2 + y^2 \ge 1\}$$
The integral is the following:
$$\iiint_D(x^2+y^2)\,dx\,dy\,dz$$
Now, I made a picture and I got some intuition about the possible range of the three coordinates. Here are my thoughts:
$$-2\le x \le2$$
$$\sqrt{1-x^2} \le y \le \sqrt{2-x^2}$$
$$-\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2} \le z \le \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$$
I know that only the range for $z$ is right. Because for $y$ I got only the positive part between the two circles, and $x$ actually doesn't take all the values between $-2$ and $2$. 
I should add this restrictions for $x$
$-2\le x \le-1$ and $1\le x \le2$ and for $y$ apart from what has been written above I got $$-\sqrt{2-x^2} \le y \le -\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

But, now, the question is how am I supposed to plug this additional restrictions into the integral? Thanks for you answer

Comment: Are you familiar with spherical coordinates?

Comment: You have a cylinder, a sphere and something depending on $x^2+y^2$, and you choose *cartesian coordinates*?

Comment: D is the interior of a sphere of radius 2, intersected with the *outside* of the circular cylinder of radius 1 whose axis coincides with the z-axis. In particular, your x range does not satisfy the "outside the cylinder" requirement.

Comment: its a sphere with a hole drilled through it lol

Comment: I tried also with ploar coordinates, but i don't know how to find tha range for phi and theta...

Comment: Ro is between 0 and 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spherical coordinates $(r,\theta,\phi)$, we have $r\le 2$ and $r\sin(\theta)\ge 1$.

Therefore, the volume integral can be written

$$\int_D (x^2+y^2)\,dV=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\pi/6}^{5\pi/6} \int_{\csc(\theta)}^2 r^2\sin^2(\theta)\,r^2\sin(\theta)\,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: thank you! I see now how it's done. Amd yes I can take it from there. One more question. How did you know theta was between pi/6 and pi?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Note that $$\csc(\theta) \le r\le 2\implies \sin(\theta)\ge \frac12 \implies \theta \ge \pi/6$$

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you sooo muc!

Comment: Shouldn't the upper limit of the $\theta$ integration be $\frac{5\pi}{6}$? The hole goes all the way through the sphere.

Comment: @Nick Yes.  Good catch.